# No resource that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value @drawable\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha)

Tags: android, xml

I am new to Android Studio and the API level is 23. This tutorial on lynda.com I was using had a pre-made project and when I loaded it, I got these errors
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jg1Z.jpg)

I looked through the file directory until I got to the file "abc_textfield_search_material.xml" that was apparently missing the values and this is what the file contained:[xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw4LD.jpg). It looks like the things that the error says are missing are there, so there seems to be a problem with referencing them.

I went to my drawable file in my Android studio and the file was empty so made a new file and copied the contents from the file in the directory but that didn't do anything.

Please help and thanks.

Comment: how you resolved this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of missing  support lib. please check it is added or not,
if not please add these dependencies in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, the Android support library, rev 23.1.1 is already installed and those two lines are already in my build.gradle file. Is there anywhere else I could look for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of missing support lib. please check it is added or not, if not please add these dependencies in your build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

}`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Windows PC:
Reduce the path length of your project, since Windows does not allow very long paths. Maximum path lengths of windows computers are apparently 260 characters.

**Background:**
The same error happened on my Windows 10 computer. I found this comment on GitHub which solved it for me: https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/issues/71#issuecomment-238561858

Basically, my project path was too long. I moved the project to something like `C:/MyProjects/MyNewProject`. Now it works.

**Disclaimer:** This may not solve your specific issue, but I too had the same error message, and the compile lines already in place.